# Pandas: Sum and aggregate by daily amounts after multiplying exchange rates look-up by same dates from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, merge, currency

thank you in advance for your help.

I am completely new to Python, and I tried different things to achieve what is required (mostly using `groupby()`) but everything has failed so far.

I have a data frame that includes multiple transactions in different currencies for the same day (116200 rows):

| Index | Account No | Withdrawal AMT | Deposit AMT | Dates | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12345567 | 100 | 300 | 2015-01-01 | eur |
| 1 | 12345567 | 100 | 300 | 2015-01-01 | usd |
| 2 | 12345567 | 100 | 300 | 2015-01-01 | gbp |
| 3 | 12345567 | 100 | 300 | 2015-01-01 | eur |
| 4 | 34334123 | 100 | 300 | 2015-01-02 | usd |
| 5 | 34334123 | 100 | 300 | 2015-01-02 | gbp |

I have two separate data frames with the exchanges rates for each day (one for EUR to GBP and one for USD to GBP):

| Index | EURO-GBP | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.634 | 2015-01-01 |
| 1 | 1.6676 | 2015-01-02 |
| 2 | 1.4554 | 2015-01-03 |
| 3 | 1.23455 | 2015-01-04 |

| Index | USD-GBP | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.934 | 2015-01-01 |
| 1 | 0.943 | 2015-01-02 |
| 2 | 0.834 | 2015-01-03 |
| 3 | 0.945 | 2015-01-04 |

First, I need to figure out a way to convert the first values of the data frame to GBP. As you have noticed each day includes transactions in different currencies, so any tip on how to do that would be more than appreciated!

Then, I want to create a data frame with just one day per row for the same day, i.e., merge each row with the corresponding daily sum of Withdrawal and deposit columns:

| Index | Withdrawal AMT | Deposit AMT | Dates | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 600 | 2015-01-01 | GBP |
| 1 | 3000 | 500 | 2015-01-02 | GBP |
| 2 | 2000 | 700 | 2015-01-03 | GBP |

Thank you again for taking the time to read my post!

P.S. All numbers are random!

Comment: Take the average per day in your exchange dataframe. Then merge this table with your transactions tables based on dates. Now you can multiply the exchange rate with the amounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

(Assuming your main dataframe is named `df1`, the exchange rate dataframes are `df_xr_eur` and `df_xr_usd`):

```
# Split the main dataframe by currency
df1_eur = df1[df1['Currency'] == 'eur'].copy()
df1_usd = df1[df1['Currency'] == 'usd'].copy()
df1_gbp = df1[df1['Currency'] == 'gbp'].copy()

# Calculate GBP equivalent of currency values
df1_eur['Withdrawal AMT'] *= df1_eur['Dates'].map(df_xr_eur.set_index('Dates')['EURO-GBP'])
df1_eur['Deposit AMT'] *= df1_eur['Dates'].map(df_xr_eur.set_index('Dates')['EURO-GBP'])

df1_usd['Withdrawal AMT'] *= df1_usd['Dates'].map(df_xr_usd.set_index('Dates')['USD-GBP'])
df1_usd['Deposit AMT'] *= df1_usd['Dates'].map(df_xr_usd.set_index('Dates')['USD-GBP'])

# Assemble the previously split datrframes after exchange rate calculation
df2 = pd.concat([df1_eur, df1_usd, df1_gbp]).assign(Currency='GBP')

# Aggregate by `Dates`
df_final = df2.groupby('Dates').agg({'Withdrawal AMT': 'sum',
                                     'Deposit AMT': 'sum',
                                     'Currency': 'first'
                                    }).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_final)


        Dates  Withdrawal AMT  Deposit AMT Currency
0  2015-01-01           520.2       1560.6      GBP
1  2015-01-02           194.3        582.9      GBP
```

Comment: thank you very much for that! I got stuck in the last line of code though!  I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". I converted the withdrawal and deposit to numeric, but for some reason, I cannot convert the currency to string (is currency an object) with this code ```str(df_2["Currency"]). Any tips on that?

Comment: @SpaniasCharalampos  Yes, if your amount columns are in string type, you have to convert them first.   You can convert them by e.g. `df1_usd['Withdrawal AMT'] = df1_usd['Withdrawal AMT'].astype(float)`.   For string type of Currency, probably you don't need to convert it since we are not summing on it.

Comment: @SpaniasCharalampos  But it seems strange if your amount fields are not numeric, our calculation steps should also fail.   You can check the data types of `df2` by `df2.dtypes` to check the data type before running the last line.

Comment: If I proceed and calculate the GBP equivalent of currency values at your initial code:
```transactions_eur['WITHDRAWAL AMT'] *= transactions_eur['dates_parsed'].map(euro_rates.set_index('dates_parsed')['EUR-GBP'])```
then the "Withdrawal" column gets full with NaNs.

I tried to convert to float prior to making this step:
```transactions_eur["WITHDRAWAL AMT"].astype(float)```

but when I use the followin code to check the type, they are still an object!
```transactions_eur["WITHDRAWAL AMT"]```

As a result, in the final step, I get the type error.

Comment: @SpaniasCharalampos The `NaN` values appear when there is no match of `Dates` in the currency dataframe.  You have to make sure the currency dataframe contains each `Dates` in the main dataframe.   Also the date formats in both dataframe have to be the same (otherwise, can't match dates).

Comment: @SpaniasCharalampos In your data type conversion, have you assigned back to the original column after conversion ?   You have to use `transactions_eur["WITHDRAWAL AMT"] = transactions_eur["WITHDRAWAL AMT"].astype(float)` instead of just `transactions_eur["WITHDRAWAL AMT"].astype(float)`

Comment: @SpaniasCharalampos  Probably you are still very new to Python and Pandas and missed out many essential steps and details.  No problem, if I'm still around my computer, I will try best to answer you.

Comment: I am completely new to python and pandas. I have just done the Kaggle courses and that task seemed to be above my current capabilities as you can clearly see! I will fight with it a bit more though as I enjoy getting frustrated the whole day for coding issues :D! 

P.S. No, I did not even assign it back to the original column after conversion! I am that dumb! I am dissapointed with myself at this stage!

Comment: @SpaniasCharalampos  No worry, this kind of mistakes is common to quite a lot of newbies.  Sure you can get it through and become proficient in Python / Pandas coding by more practices together with your great enthusiasm with it  :-)